# how to get Null records from oracle database if column is Number type and nullable

Tags: oracle, jpa, nativequery, hibernate-native-query

I have Oracle database table with three columns i.e Id,RTOName,VehicleCode. my table looks like below

[image]

RTOName is the varchar2 type and VehicleCode is NUMBER(2,0) and is nullable field.
So I have the data like below and I want to fetch the records with Some VehicleCode and with null value. The table design like this already done so changing that will impact a lot in my application. I have a JPA Native Query that I used like this and I want to fetch the records with null values.

```
Query query = createNativeQuery("select RTOName,VehicleCode from tbl_vehiclecodes WHERE VehicleCode=#vCode");
query.setParameter("vCode", vehicleCode);
```

From above Query I will get only Non null valued record. Eg. for vCode parameter 61 I will get
Marathalli,61. If my vCode is null I have a problem and I wont get any record.
How to achieve this in Native Query?
I know that we can use IS NULL in the Query in where clause. Since I have some numbers here In my case how to solve this? Any help

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `OR` here,

Following query will give you records with matched records for parameter `vCode` along with rows having null and in case of `vCode` is null you get the records only with `null` values.

```
Query query = createNativeQuery("select RTOName,VehicleCode from tbl_vehiclecodes WHERE (VehicleCode is null or VehicleCode=#vCode)");
```

*Edit: considering the doubts from @Ranagal*

If you want like in case of null value passed to `vCode` you want all the records having value in `vehiclecode` and also with null then we need to change the query like,

```
Query query = createNativeQuery("select RTOName,VehicleCode from tbl_vehiclecodes WHERE (VehicleCode is null or VehicleCode=coalesce(#vCode,VehicleCode))");
```

Comment: @Chidambar, your question does not sound quite clear. What exactly is your input ? And what exactly is the output for that input ? Do you mean to say that sometimes you pass NULL as input for VehicleCode and sometimes you pass a number ? And what do you want to display in each case ? Do you want the null VehicleCode to be included in addition to the non-null VehicleCode ? Kindly explain.

Comment: @Chidambar Shiragalle, Did you try with first option I proposed , I believe it fits to your requirement.

Comment: Hi @Ranagal, Yes sometimes I will pass NULL value to the input parameter vehicleCode and sometime number. In case of NULL input parameter, I want the results with NULL vehicleCode and in case of number I want the result with Number in vehicleCode. I don't want NULL vehicleCode results when I input number. Thanks

Comment: Hi @Sujitmohanty30, Your first solution works very well for my case. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @ Chidambar Shiragalle, Thanks and could you accept it and give it a tick if you feel this resolves your problem.